# How to remove extra string "Line2D" in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have  a string "Line2D" appended in the beginning of my matplotlib legend. How to get rid of it? A simple python script that reproduces this problem is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x=np.linspace(0,1,20)
y=np.sin(2*x)
z=np.cos(2*x)

p1, = plt.plot(x,y, label='sin(x)')
p2, = plt.plot(x,z, label='cos(x)')
plt.legend([p1, p2])
plt.show()
```

I get a figure in which I want to get rid of the extra string "Line2D" in the legend. I do not have enough reputation to post images. I was using anaconda python if that matters.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you pass just one list to `legend`, it has to be the labels you want to show, not the objects whose labels you want to show.  It is converting those line objects to strings, which gives `Line2D(...)`.

Since you gave the lines labels when you created them, you don't need to pass anything to `legend`.  Just `plt.legend()` will automatically use the labels you provided.

Comment: I require a rep of 15 to vote. How sad! :(  can someone do it for me?

Comment: @CorruptedStack: You can still accept the answer by clicking the check mark near the voting buttons.  (This will also earn you rep for yourself.)

Comment: funny I have to wait 6 minutes!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2])`.